# How to use cookie in ajax file

Tags: php

I have code that uses ajax in order to pull and print data from DB.

ajax run PHP file that does that. This file read data from the cookie and use it, but because I'm using ajax and run file "away" from the website I don't think it can call to cookies...

how can I read cookie inside the ajax file?

AJAX FILE

```
switch ($_COOKIE['user_lang'])
{
    case "ES":
        $langDir = SPANISH                  
    break;

    case "EN":
        $langDir = ENGLISH
    break;  
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try to print the `$_COOKIE`

Comment: is it hosted on the same webserver/domain name?

Comment: yes. right now i'm running it from my local pc - localhost ; @Tschallacka

Comment: then $_COOKIE is populated with the same stuff you set via other php scripts programs. just do `echo '<pre>';var_debug($_COOKIE); ` and request the php file with your browser to see which cookie values are set.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it .

```
    function readCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname+"=";
        var cookies = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie).split(';');
        var cval = [];
        for(var i=0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            if (cookies[i].trim().indexOf(name) == 0) {
                cval = cookies[i].trim().split("=");
            }   
        }
        return (cval.length > 0) ? cval[1] : "";
    }


    switch (readCookie(['user_lang']))
    {
        case "ES":
            $langDir = SPANISH                  
        break;

        case "EN":
            $langDir = ENGLISH
        break;  
    }
```